# Contact Form 7 ограничение отправок формы?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Подскажите, как ограничить количество нажатий на кнопку отправки, что б пользователь, после того как пройдет все обязательные поля к заполнению мог только один раз отправить форму кнопкой Submit.

```
<form>
some requered* fields

 <div class="cf7__wrapper--submit a-up a-delay-1 animated fadeInUp animation-end">
    <div class="button--primary">
      <p><input class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit cf7__submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><span class="wpcf7-spinner"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true"></div>

</form>
```

Необходимо как-то устанавливать disabled, но только после того как все заполненно корректно. Пробовал так

```
const wpcf7Elm =document.querySelector( '.wpcf7-form' );
const sendBtn = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-submit');

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    sendBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout(function(){sendBtn.removeAttribute("disabled")}, 3000);
    console.log("SEND FORM");
}, false );
```

но это глупость. Оно не учитывает что поля не заполены корректно... Не могу найти правильный ответ, подскажите, кто решал данную проблему ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там есть ряд [DOM событий](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/contact-form-7/sovety-haki-sekrety#sobytiya-dom)

Comment: Замените wpcf7submit на wpcf7mailsent.

Comment: За совет конечно, спасибо, но оно всё равно не отрабатывает как надо. Fetch запросы продолжают отсылаться на сервер, независимо от подключеного действия. Может что-то не так блокирую ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо за совет, опробовал. Тоже как-то не подошло. Так же пробовал поставить отслеживание на событие `wpcf7beforesubmit` , но тогда кнопка блокируеться в независимости правильно пользователь прошел обязательніе поля или нет. Всегда блокирует.